# windows CLI commands to cutomize command line interface

Tags: command-line

What is the command to make the command line interface icon to appear on the windows 8 desktop permanently? so i can double click on it and use the command line easily.

Answer (score 0):

(Works in Windows 10, not sure if it's exactly the same in Windows 8)

If you search for `cmd` in the Start Menu, you can right-click it and click "Open file location". Then copy the shortcut using Ctrl+C and paste it to your Desktop with Ctrl+V.